# How to add return value from function into dataframe Column?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I want to add multiple return values from function into one column, for example, here I am splitting the combined hours and minutes and adding into different variables "hour" and "minute" each. Now I want to add these values in one data frame column.

```
def issuetimesplit(x):
    hour = str(x)[:-2]
    minutes = str(x)[-2:]
    time = print(f"{hour} : {minutes}")
    return time

for i,v in timeData.items():
    issuetimesplit(v)
```

Comment: `print` doesn't return anything. You're assigning `time = None`. Not that that's going to solve your issue.

Comment: Try using DataFrame.apply() and pass your function as parameter and save the return value as column. Make sure you apply the function on correct axis. refer the below link for the same.

[DataFrame.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas.DataFrame.apply)

Comment: @Mike is correct. rather than using print statement simply return the formatted string.

`return f"{hour} : {minutes}"`

Comment: Please, do not forget to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer, if it was right, @Ujwala Nanavare

Answer (score 3):

Let me sum the comments up.

1. You can't use `print` to define a string variable.
2. In the function, your new string can be returned immediately. It means `time` variable is not needed. However, it is not a mistake to define it.
3. You can use `apply()` function, that could be a solution for your problem.

The code is following.

```
# import pandas
import pandas as pd

# define function
def make_new_time_feature(row):
    hour = row['old_time_feature'][:-2]
    minutes = row['old_time_feature'][-2:]
    return f'{hour} : {minutes}'

# call apply
your_df['new_time_feature'] = your_df.apply(lambda row: make_new_time_feature(row), axis=1)
```